# Compare elapsed time (eg : 08:00 am) to current time android

Tags: android, time, compare, elapsed

I am having an `array` of time . I am retrieving every time from it to compare it to the current time , so that remove the elapsed time and make a new `array` which contains left time.

I am comparing the elapsed time from the

```
String timeSlots[] = {"08:00 AM to 08:30 AM", "08:30 AM to 09:00 AM", "09:00 AM to 09:30 AM", "09:30 AM to 10:00 AM", "10:00 AM to 10:30 AM", "10:30 AM to 11:00 AM", "11:00 AM to 11:30 AM", "11:30 AM to 12:00 PM", "12:00 PM to 12:30 PM", "12:30 PM to 01:00 PM", "01:00 PM to 01:30 PM", "01:30 PM to 02:00 PM", "02:00 PM to 02:30 PM", "02:30 PM to 03:00 PM", "03:00 PM to 03:30 PM", "03:30 PM to 04:00 PM", "04:00 PM to 04:30 PM", "04:30 PM to 05:00 PM", "05:00 PM to 05:30 PM", "05:30 PM to 06:00 PM", "06:00 PM to 06:30 PM", "06:30 PM to 07:00 PM", "07:00 PM to 07:30 PM", "07:30 PM to 08:00 PM", "08:00 PM to 08:30 PM", "08:30 PM to 09:00PM"};


for (int i = 0; i < timeSlots.length; i++) {
            timeSlotesTemp[i] = timeSlots[i].substring(0, 8);
            removeElapsedTime(timeSlotesTemp[i].toLowerCase());
        }

public void removeElapsedTime(String elapsedTime) { // elapsedTime = 08:00 pm
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
            Date elapsedDate = dateFormat.parse(elapsedTime);
            String strElapsedDate=dateFormat.format(elapsedDate);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date currentDate = calendar.getTime();
            String calculatedDate = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
            if (new Date(strElapsedDate).compareTo(new Date(calculatedDate))<0) {
                finalTimeSlotes.remove(elapsedTime);
            }
             else if (new Date(strElapsedDate).compareTo(new Date(calculatedDate))>0) {
                finalTimeSlotes.add(elapsedTime);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "" + e);
        }
    }
```

I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error: 03:30 pm` while comparing the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you compare the Date object instead of date String.
Here is sample code.

```
   public static void removeElapsedTime(String elapsedTime) { // elapsedTime = 08:00 pm
        try {
            Date elapsedDate = getDateFromTimeString(elapsedTime);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date currentDate = calendar.getTime();
            if (elapsedDate.compareTo(currentDate) < 0) {
                finalTimeSlotes.remove(elapsedTime);
            } else if (elapsedDate.compareTo(currentDate) > 0) {
                finalTimeSlotes.add(elapsedTime);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("" + e);
        }
        return;
    }

    public static Date getDateFromTimeString(String time) {
        String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
        SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = df1.parse(currentDate + " " + time);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }
```

Edit:
Reason for `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error: 03:30 pm` is you are passing just time String to create new Date Object. You also need to pass Date String along with Time String.

Comment: @karthikkolanji **new Date(String date)is deprecated As of JDK version 1.1**. so try to avoid use of it.

Comment: @karthikkolanji Happy to help you. :-)